# How to wrap nested string (metadata) into TagGroup

Tags: dm-script

My imported metadata has a pre-defined nested structure (an example show in the following), which is a single string after imported to DM. 
The whole metadata and each branch level are included in brace marks {}, all the key and key values are included by quotation marks "" and deliminated by colon :

My question is, how to convert the data and wrap them into a TagGroup object so that indexing, searching and data accessing operations can be done much easier?

Thanks!

Here is an example:

```
{
    "Acquisition": {
        "AcquisitionStartDatetime": {
            "DateTime": "1473763749"
        },
        "AcquisitionDatetime": {
            "DateTime": "0"
        },
        "BeamType": "",
        "SourceType": "Monochromator"
    },
    "BinaryResult": {
        "AcquisitionUnit": "",
        "CompositionType": "",
        "DetectorIndex": "3",
        "Detector": "HAADF",
        "PixelSize": {
            "width": "5.408370946750477e-010",
            "height": "5.408370946750477e-010"
        },
        "PixelUnitX": "m",
        "PixelUnitY": "m",
        "Offset": {
            "x": "-2.769085924736244e-007",
            "y": "-2.769085924736244e-007"
        },
        "Encoding": ""
    },
    "Sample": "",
    "GasInjectionSystems": ""
}
```

Comment: Actually, this metadata is converted from FEI Velox 1.2 data (.emd), an HDF5-based file format. I am attempting to implement a working script to do file import. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems you will need a moderately sophisticated recursive string parser, something that isn't easily provided as a short answer to a question on this forum.  I have done a similar sort of parser for XML import into DM and would be interested in helping you with your application.  If you would be interested in a collaborative effort, please contact me via the web-site/contact info provided in my profile.

Comment: Having a Velox import script is for sure something a lot of people might be interested in! Once you've something working, it would be great if you could submit it to the [DM scripting database](http://www.felmi-zfe.at/dm-script/) as well.

Comment: @BmyGuest that's what i'm intended to.

Comment: @MikeKundmann Thanks for the hints! I am still "learning by doing". I will contact you later when this would be really be critical to me. :-)

Comment: @BmyGuest Just finished a working version, and tested this week. uploaded to the database few minutes ago. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Fixed code now**

I'm sure some a more cleaned up version is possible, but it does the task:

```
Class CMetaStringToTagGroup
{
    // Find next string bracketed by " in input string, starting search
    // at given index. Returns string and end-position of search
    string FindNextKeyName( object self, string input, number & searchPos )
    {
        number totalLength = len( input )
        number start = 0, end = 0
        while( searchPos < totalLength )
        {
            searchpos++
            if ( "\"" == input.mid(searchpos-1,1) )
            {
                if ( !start ) 
                    start = searchpos-1
                else
                    {
                    end = searchpos-1
                    return input.mid(start+1,end-start-1)
                    }
            }
        }
        return ""
    }

    // Returns the next of either "{" ,  "}" or """ after a collon ":"
    string GetNextIndicator( object self, string input, number & searchPos )
    {
        number totalLength = len( input )
        while( searchPos < totalLength )
        {
            searchpos++        
            if ( "{" == input.mid(searchpos-1,1) )
                return "{"
            if ( "}" == input.mid(searchpos-1,1) )
                return "}"
            if ( "\"" == input.mid(searchpos-1,1) )
                return "\""
        }
        return ""
    }

    // In a tag-path string, find location of last colon 
    number findLastColon( object self, string input )
    {
        number totalLength = len( input )
        number lastPos = -1
        number searchPos = 0
        while( searchPos < totalLength )
        {
            searchpos++
            if ( ":" == input.mid(searchpos-1,1) )
                lastPos = searchpos-1
        }
        return lastPos
    }

    // Parse textstring and create taggroup from it
    TagGroup CreateTagFromText( object self, string input )
    {
        TagGroup rootTG = NewTagGroup()
        string currentPath = ""

        number totalLength = len( input )
        number searchPos = 0 
        number searchPos2
        string keyName, indicator
        while( searchPos < totalLength )
        {
            // search for new key or closing bracket, whatever first 
            searchPos2 = searchPos
            indicator = self.GetNextIndicator( input, searchPos2 )
            keyName = self.FindNextKeyName( input, searchPos )
            if ( ( "}" == indicator ) && (searchpos2<searchPos ) )
            {
                // decrease hierachy
                number cutPos = self.findLastColon( currentPath )
                currentPath = left( currentPath, cutPos )
                result("\n DEC ")
                searchPos = searchPos2
            }
            else
            {
                // Either add value or new  sub-tagGroup
                if ( "" == keyname ) break; // No more keys found
                indicator = self.GetNextIndicator( input, searchPos )
                if ( "" == indicator ) break;   // No more indicator found -- should not happen!

                if ( "{" == indicator )
                {
                    // increase hierachy
                    currentPath += ":" + keyname
                    rootTg.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( currentPath, NewTagGroup() )
                    result("\n INC ("+keyname+")")
                }
                else if ( "\"" == indicator )
                {
                    // Add value
                    searchPos--
                    string valStr = self.FindNextKeyName( input, searchPos )
                    rootTg.TagGroupSetTagAsString( currentPath + ":" + keyname, valStr )
                    result("\n   VAL("+keyname+") ")
                }
            }
        }
        return rootTg
    }
}

{
    // Reading input text
    number fileID = OpenFileForReading("C:\\test.txt")
    object fStream = NewStreamFromFileReference(fileID,1)
    string inputStr = fStream.StreamReadAsText(0, fStream.StreamGetSize())

    // Parsing text
    number searchPos = 0
    TagGroup con = alloc(CMetaStringToTagGroup).CreateTagFromText( inputStr )
    con.TagGroupopenBrowserwindow("",0)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The results seem to be not completely correct... "Acquisition", "BinaryResult", "Sample" and "GasInjectionSystem" should be in the same level. According to my observation to the structure of the metadata,  folders have the pattern ["FOLDER_NAME" : { ] and entries have the pattern ["ENTRY_NAME" : "ENTRY_VALUE"], better to skip the first { and the last } character. I will try to follow your code first...

Comment: @w4m fixed it now.

Comment: BTW, is there any existing function that writes this nice TagGroup to the image tag? According to the document in DM help and your handbook, I found only the groups of functions "Set...Note(image, string)".

Comment: inserting a line "img.SetStringNote(currentPath + ":" + keyname, valStr)" in the function "CreateTagFromText" seems at least a way to add the hierachical tags to a image, of course, one need an additional varabal (image & img) in this function.

Comment: You are looking for `ImageGetTagGroup()`, `TagGroupCopyTagsFrom()` and `TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup()`. Maybe also make use of `TagGroupClone()` to ensure you're not unintentionally have a single taggroup 'attached' to more than one image in memory. (There are usecases one wants that, though;). If you have any issues, ask it as separate question.

Answer (score 2):

As Mike has pointed out in the comments, this is rather a tedious than difficult task. Best to create a little parser script in a separate class which turns formats

`"NAME: {` into *TagGroups* of label NAME plus an increased hierachy level.

and

`"NAME": "VALUE"` into *Tags* of label NAME and value VALUE.

and

`}` into a 'reduce hierachy level' step.

Note, that you can always use String when creating the taggroup, even if you want to read it out as number at a later time point.

Recursivly browse and remember the "taggroup-level" you are in, so that each new tag is added at that level. Skip invalid text sections.

The F1 help documenation of DigitalMicrograph has a section on strings, which lists the commands you're most likely to need:

```
String StringAppend( String s1, String s2 ) 
Number StringCompare( String s1, String s2 ) 
Boolean StringIsValid( String str ) 
String StringToLower( String str ) 
String StringToUpper( String str ) 
Number len( String str )
String left( String str, Number count )
String mid( String str, Number offset, Number count )
String right( String str, Number count )
Number find( String s1, String s2 )
Number val( String str )
```

Additionally, I find it sometimes useful to user the tert-operator for strings like in

```
number isOK = 1
string str =  isOK == 1 ? "true" : "false"
```

Also, when parsing, watch out for tabulator and line return characters. (Use \t and \n to search for them. You might need to use "\n" and "\t" when specifying int in a string, as \ will be interpreted as control character.)